Find $\cos $v using trigonometric identities (a.k.a., trigonometric one)
Using trigonometric identities:
Find $\cos~v$ if $\sin v = \frac{1}{2}$ and $v$ in the first quadrant.
Attempt:
$\cos^2(v) + \sin^2(v) = 1$
$\cos^2(v) + \sin^2(v) - \sin^2(v) = 1 - \sin^2(v)$
$\cos^2(v) = 1 - \sin^2(v)$
$\sqrt{\cos^2(v)} = \pm \sqrt{1 - \sin^2(v)}$
$\cos v = \pm \sqrt{1 - \sin^2(v)}$
$\cos v = \pm \sqrt{1 - (\frac{1}{2})^2}$
$cos~v = \pm \sqrt{1 - (\frac{1}{4})}$
Confused by this part:
$$1 - (\frac{1}{4})$$
on the calculator, this is obviously wrong answer:
$$\sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{4}} = 0.8660254038$$
Correct answer according to final solution:
$\cos v = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$
EDIT: There seems to be a lot of confusion here. I just recently began a course in linear algebra and calculus, and I haven't done math for a while. The course is given in distance, self-paced. There is online meeting with teacher once a week. If you get stuck, Google, however, sometimes this does not help so, I decided to post here after countless hours.

It's a type. That should read $1 - \frac{1}{4}$ without the square.

@SeanRoberson, noticed I had missed removing it. Thanks. But, how does one go from $1 - \frac{1}{4}$ to $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ ?

You don't, But using $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} = \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}$, it's easy to go from $\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4}}$ to $\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$.

@Henriksupportsthecommunity, thx. Please explain this, thanks. I am a bit confused. It's not clear how $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ that is derived.

@YvesDaoust I did, my TI-84 Plus did not return fraction from the decimals. Sorry!

All you miss is a series of quite simple rewrites:
$$
1-\frac{1}{4} = \frac{4}{4}-\frac{1}{4} = \frac{4-1}{4} = \frac{3}{4}
$$
If you take the square root and use $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} = \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}$:
$$
\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4}} = \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{4}}
$$
And I guess you know what $\sqrt{4}$ is.

@RishwanthSV, I just started out learning this stuff. The course began a week ago and all online, meeting once a week with teacher. I am new to the subject and decided to Google for countless hours, with no clear answers and lots of confusions, I decided to post here in the end.

@Rishwanth The OP (who probably prefers "she" pronouns) is having difficulties with the arithmetic of rational expressions under the radical sign. She is clearly confused about how to make sense of (and to evaluate) $\sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{4}}$. Such things are difficult to Google, unless you know (or guess) the appropriate terminology. Whereas discussion with an actual human can quickly clarify matters.

Ok I am sorry for that
